# eclipse console suddenly showing INFO

Tags: eclipse

I'm using a apache HttpClient and I've started seeing some INFO output on the eclipse console:

```
0    [main] INFO  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector  - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
3    [main] INFO  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector  - Retrying request
3861 [pool-1-thread-25] INFO  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector  - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
3861 [pool-1-thread-25] INFO  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector  - Retrying request
3913 [pool-1-thread-16] INFO  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase  - Response content length is not known
```

To my knowledge, nothing has changed. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your logging library. `HttpClient` likely depends on `commons-logging`, which automatically picks up a logging implementation in your classpath (either `java.util.logging` or `log4j`) which by default writes on the console.

Comment: How can I track down such an implementation?

Comment: Check your project libraries in Eclipse's project explorer and look for anything to do with `log4j`. `java.util.logging` is bundled with the jdk as far as I remember, so maybe you have a `logging.properties` file somewhere in your project.

Comment: Thanks. This only seems to happen for the specific apache HttpClient wrapper and only on my machine. I'm guessing something's up with my Eclipse.